# Spring RabbitMQ - add bindings during runtime

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I've been following the guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/#initial for setting up rabbitMQ communication via Spring. Queues, Exchanges, Bindings are declared and initialised on Application startup. The code, pretty much like the tutorial:

```
    public static final String SPRINGQUEUE = "springqueue";

    public static final String SPRINGEXCHANGE = "springexchange";

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(SPRINGQUEUE, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(SPRINGEXCHANGE);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("routingkey1");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(SPRINGQUEUE);
        container.setMessageListener(listener);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListener createListener(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return new Listener(queue, exchange);
    }
```

This listens to "routingkey1" just as expected, however, I would like to change the keys to listen for dynamically during runtime. I know this is possible using the RabbitMQ Java client, by simply binding a channel multiple times. Is there any way to do this through spring AMQP as well?

Answer (score 1):

See `RabbitAdmin` API:

```
/**
 * Declare a binding of a queue to an exchange.
 * @param binding a description of the binding to declare.
 */
void declareBinding(Binding binding);
```

for example.

You don't listen to the routing key: you listen to the queue. The routing key is a part of publisher logic: you publish a message to the exchange with some routing key. The RabbitMQ broker already decides to what queue place this message to. Therefore see if your expectations with dynamic bindings and listening is what is possible with an AQMP protocol.